# App installation failed only with iOS8.4

Tags: ios, installation, verification

I am getting "App installation failed. The application could not be verified." error when trying to install my app on an iOS8.4 device. It will install on earlier iOS devices like 8.1. I can run it in the debugger on all devices but I get this error when I drag the ipa file to the Devices window to install it. What is new in iOS8.4 that prevents apps from being verified that was not in previous releases? I have made sure the app has been deleted before trying to install it.

Comment: The problem is probably that you forgot to register this device with the Member Center and add it to your provisioning profile.

Comment: "I drag the ipa file to the Devices window to install it" I've never heard of doing that.

Comment: The devices are in my provisioning profile. The ipa file is from a separate build machine. To install it on a device from Xcode go to Xcode->Window->Devices and drag and drop the ipa file into the Install Apps section. Only with iOS 8.4 am I seeing this error. It installs fine on previous versions of iOS.